# Why am I not allowed to put a parentheses in my for loop?

Tags: bash, scripting

My code is:

```
dnafile=$1

for seq in (fold -w3 $dnafile | uniq); do
              fold -w3 $dnafile | grep $seq | wc -l
              echo $seq
              echo '(new line)'
done
```

I receive the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: (1) Man pages are hard to read, but they are the best way to learn this stuff. (2) You should use quotes for `"$dnafile"` and `"$seq"`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want to count the number of unique lines resulting from `fold -w3 $dnafile`.  This can be done without a loop:

```
fold -w3 "$dnafile" | sort | uniq -c
```

The `sort` would sort the lines of the output from `fold` while `uniq -c` would count the number of times each line occurs consecutively.

The output will be one line for each unique line in the `fold` result prefixed with a number.

---

The syntax error comes from the fact that a command substitution (i.e. a construct that is replaced by the output of a command) needs to look like `$( ... )`. I'm uncertain that inserting the missing `$` will actually make your code work though, as the shell will still split the resulting text on newlines and spaces, but since we don't know what the input data looks like it's difficult to speculate.

Having a sub-shell, `(...)`, in a for loop at that position is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You lost the `$` by `(fold -w3 $dnafile | uniq)`. Try this: `$(fold -w3 $dnafile | uniq)`.

`$()` is the syntax for command substitution, while `()` introduces a subshell.

Comment: It should also be quoted unless you want to split and glob the result.  Surprisingly, this is even true in zsh.

Comment: @Kevin, `zsh` does the split and not the glob. Here, the OP wants to split, otherwise there wouldn't be any point having a `for` loop.

Comment: Note that in the `fish` shell, command substitution is with `(...)` instead of `$(...)` or `\`...\`` (in `fish` the syntax of the `for` loop is different though). And it also splits (though on newline only) and not globs. All shells split on cmdsubst as that's often what you want to do.

Comment: OP may still want `IFS="\n"`.